# Zero variance-series and NaN error in CAR models - CARBayes (S.CARbym) in R

Tags: r, nan

I've been trying to run a **CAR model** (CARBayes package - `S.CARbym` function in R) to predict the risk of visceral leishmaniasis diseases in Sao Paulo state, Brazil. The covariates are precipitation, altitude, temperature, and distance of highways. When I run the model with **all raw covariates** there is an error: `"Error in ar.yw.default(x, aic = aic, order.max = order.max, na.action = na.action,  :  zero-variance series"`

I tried to **adjust the covariates** values with similar ranges based on

> (observed data - mean)/(standard deviation of observed data)

`equation=LV~offset(log(Total_Pop))+precipitation+altitude+temperature+distance
model <- S.CARbym(formula=equation, family="zip", formula.omega=~1, data=spat.data, W=W2, burnin=100000, n.sample=300000, thin=20)`

Then I could run the model but the DIC values results = `NaN`.

My data `(Y)` has a lot of "zeros" so the `zip` family seems to be the most suitable. The total of data is 643 features. I used population as the offset.

Individually, for each covariate, it works. But I'd like to run the model with all of them.

How can I fix this?